# Django - NoReverseMatch error not a valid function or pattern

Tags: django

The error is Reverse for **'django_with_ocr.ocr.views.list' not found. 'django_with_ocr.ocr.views.list' is not a valid view function or pattern name**

Exception value here is not a valid function or pattern name.

There is also an error  '**charmap' codec can't encode character '\ufb01' in position 843: character maps to**

```
views.py

from django.shortcuts import render

from django.shortcuts import render

from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse

from .models import Document
from .forms import DocumentForm

from django.http import HttpResponse
import csv
import ipdb
from Cython.Compiler.Buffer import context

try:
        import Image
except ImportError:
        from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

global i
i = 0

def list(request):
    global i
    # Handle file upload
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newdoc = Document(docfile=request.FILES['docfile'])
            newdoc.save()

            i += 1 
            # import ipdb;ipdb.set_trace()
            d = Document.objects.get(id=i)

            #print d.docfile
            k=pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(d.docfile))
            #print k
            handle = open('data.txt', 'a+')
            handle.write(k)
            handle.close()

            txt_file = r"data.txt"
            csv_file = r'mycsv.csv'

            in_txt = csv.reader(open(txt_file, "r"), delimiter = ' ')
            out_csv = csv.writer(open(csv_file, 'w', encoding='utf-8'))

            out_csv.writerows(in_txt)

            # Redirect to the document list after POST
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('django_with_ocr.ocr.views.list'))
    else:
        form = DocumentForm()  # A empty, unbound form

    # Load documents for the list page
    documents = Document.objects.all()

    # Render list page with the documents and the form
    return render(request, 
        'list.html',
        {'documents': documents, 'form': form},
        context
    )
```

url.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('list/', views.list,name='list' ),
]
```

**list.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>OCR Converter</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- List of uploaded documents -->
        {% if documents %}
            <ul>
                {% for document in documents %}
                    <li><a href="{{ document.docfile.url }}">{{ document.docfile.name }}</a></li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% else %}
            <p>No documents.</p>
        {% endif %}

        <!-- Upload form. Note enctype attribute! -->
        <form action="{% url 'list' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <p>{{ form.non_field_errors }}</p>

            <p>{{ form.docfile.label_tag }} {{ form.docfile.help_text }}</p>

            <p>
                {{ form.docfile.errors }}
                {{ form.docfile }}
            </p>

            <p><input type="submit" value="Upload"/></p>
        </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

URL for the project is

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.views.generic import RedirectView

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('ocr/', include('ocr.urls')),
    path('', RedirectView.as_view(url='/ocr/list/', permanent=True)),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('django_with_ocr.ocr.views.list'))
```

You just have to call the url by its app name and url name (assuminng that `ocr` is the name of your app)

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('ocr:list'))
```

EDIT

Add

```
app_name = 'ocr'

urlpatterns = [
    path('list/', views.list,name='list' ),
]
```

Comment: I have updated HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('ocr:list'). This time the error is "NoReverseMatch at /ocr/list/".  'ocr' is not a registered namespace

Comment: @nithinpathak I updated my question with code that should work. I'm assuming that the first urls.py you posted is inside an app named `ocr`, you should clarify that in your question.